# React JS - Communication between Child and Parent and double events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, dynamic-tables

I'm facing a problem making a little application
for the Price Calculation of some Products in React. This is how my application looks like:

[image: Image 1]

What I need now is to have a global total (sum of the partial total of the ListItem components), but i don't know how to do that with React. I tried using the same "onChange" events of the smallest component (ListItem) to trigger an event on the parent like:

```
handleChange:function(event){

  this.props.onChange(event.target);

  const target = event.target;
  const name = target.name;
  const value = target.value;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
},
```

but in this way only this event has been triggered and didn't update the state.
Probably I'm missing something.

Recapping what I need is to pass the partial total, calculated in the ListItem, in the parent component, Table, so that I can calculate the global total.

```js
function Header(){
  return (
    <h1>Calcolo costo prodotti</h1>
  )
}

var ListItem = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {name: this.props.value.product.name, costo: this.props.value.product.costo, quantita: this.props.value.product.quantita, totale: 0} 
    },
  
    render: function(){
    return(
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Nome..."/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="costo" value={this.state.costo} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Costo unitario..."/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantita" value={this.state.quantita} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Quantità..."/></td>
        <td className="total">{this.calcoloTotale()}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  },
    
  handleChange:function(event){
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  },
  
  calcoloTotale: function(){
    var Ltotale = this.state.costo * this.state.quantita;
    this.setState({totale: Ltotale});
    return Ltotale;
  }
});
  
  
var Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { totale: 0 }
  },
  
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Prezzo</th> 
            <th>Quantità</th>
            <th>Totale</th>
          </tr>
          {this.props.items.map((prodotto) =>
            <ListItem key={prodotto.id} value={prodotto}/>
          )}
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var AddNewRow = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>+</button>
        Aggiungi prodotto
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Calculator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      counter: 2, lists: [{id: "0", product: {name: "Esempio 1",costo: "25",quantita: "3"}}, {id: "1", product: {name: "Esempio 2",costo: "32",quantita: "4"}}]
    }
  },
  
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Table items={this.state.lists} ids={this.counter}/>
        <AddNewRow onClick={this.addRow}/>
      </div>
    )
  },
  
  addRow: function(){
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
    var listItem = {id: this.state.counter, product:{name:"", costo: "", quantita: ""}};
    var allItem = this.state.lists.concat([listItem])
    this.setState({lists: allItem});
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Calculator />,
  document.body
);
```

EDIT 1:

```js
var totalVec = new Array();

function Header(){
  return (
    <h1>Calcolo costo prodotti</h1>
  )
}

var ListItem = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {name: this.props.value.product.name, costo: this.props.value.product.costo, quantita: this.props.value.product.quantita} 
    },
  
    render: function(){
    return(
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Nome..."/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="costo" value={this.state.costo} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Costo unitario..."/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantita" value={this.state.quantita} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Quantità..."/></td>
        <td className="total">{this.calcoloTotale()}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  },
    
  handleChange:function(event){
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
    
    this.props.updateGlobalTotal();
  },
  
  calcoloTotale: function(){
    var Ltotale = this.state.costo * this.state.quantita;
    totalVec[this.props.value.id] = Ltotale;
    return Ltotale;
  }
});
  
  
var Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { totale: 0 } 
  },
  
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Prezzo</th> 
            <th>Quantità</th>
            <th>Totale</th>
          </tr>
          {this.props.items.map((prodotto) =>
            <ListItem key={prodotto.id} value={prodotto} updateGlobalTotal={this.updateGlobalTotal}/>
          )}
        </table>
        <h1>{this.state.totale}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  },
  
  componentDidMount: function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.props.ids; i++){
      total += totalVec[i];
    }
    
    this.setState({totale: total});
  },
  
  updateGlobalTotal: function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.props.ids; i++){
      total += totalVec[i];
    }
    
    this.setState({totale: total});
  }
  
});

var AddNewRow = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>+</button>
        Aggiungi prodotto
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Calculator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      counter: 2, lists: [{id: "0", product: {name: "Esempio 1",costo: "25",quantita: "3"}}, {id: "1", product: {name: "Esempio 2",costo: "32",quantita: "4"}}]
    }
  },
  
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Table items={this.state.lists} ids={this.state.counter}/>
        <AddNewRow onClick={this.addRow}/>
      </div>
    )
  },
  
  addRow: function(){
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
    var listItem = {id: this.state.counter, product:{name:"", costo: "", quantita: ""}};
    var allItem = this.state.lists.concat([listItem])
    this.setState({lists: allItem});
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Calculator />,
  document.body
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function in the parent that changes the state of that component, then send that function as a prop to the child.

```js
var ListItem = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      return {name: this.props.value.product.name, costo: this.props.value.product.costo, quantita: this.props.value.product.quantita, totale: 0} 
    },
    
  ...
  
  calcoloTotale: function(){
    var Ltotale = this.state.costo * this.state.quantita;
    this.props.updateGlobalTotal(Ltotale);
    this.setState({totale: Ltotale});
    return Ltotale;
  }
});
  
  
var Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { totale: 0 }
  },
  updateGlobalTotal: function(value){
      this.setState({totale: this.state.totale + value})
  }
  
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Prezzo</th> 
            <th>Quantità</th>
            <th>Totale</th>
          </tr>
          {this.props.items.map((prodotto) =>
            <ListItem key={prodotto.id} value={prodotto} updateGlobalTotal={this.updateGlobalTotal}/>
          )}
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Your solution partially works, i made some adjustment, but had performance issue. I put the new code on the post if you could check out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out *Redux* as Ksyqo mentioned. However, for such needs it may not be entirely what you need as it would require you to apply a wide variety of boilerplate and cognitive overhead at this particular moment when you already have existing app code written.

For smaller project(s), one might find that you can, with better results, use *MobX* alternative as it is a bit easier to implement especially in existing applications. It is also a lot easier to reason about. It will work pretty much out of the box, with a little bit of magic involved.

Whatever the decision is, this graph holds true for both Redux and MobX, and illustrates the problem of **global state** vs **parent-child chained state** (the former is obviously much cleaner) :

[image]

Comment: MobX seems a good way to do this. I've tried @Joakim Tangnes solution and it worked but there are performance issue that make input type really slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) is made for you.

It helps you pass properties between components that do not necessarily have a child/parent relationship. Basically, it creates a global state that you can access from anywhere.

There is a lot to say about redux (we don't call it react/redux for no reason), and this is a must-have if you want to do something powerful with React.

You can find more on the Redux documentation !